# Cannot get DynamoDb TransactionCanceledException cancellation reason in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-dynamodb

In scenarios where I have a Dynamodb transaction cancelled I am unable to get the reason for the cancellation and have to figure it out on my own. I get an exception of type TransactionCanceledException that does not have any reasons, the inner exception is an HttpErrorResponseException and I have had no luck reading the content stream as this is already disposed.

I have seen this note in the docs:

> If using Java, DynamoDB lists the cancellation reasons on the
>   CancellationReasons property. This property is not set for other
>   languages. Transaction cancellation reasons are ordered in the order
>   of requested items, if an item has no error it will have NONE code and
>   Null message.

There seems to be no information whatsoever on how to handle this in .net. I hope someone has come across this and has a work around.

Comment: You can check the status of this here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/1292#issuecomment-790003583